# How to edit a scheduled task trigger

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

```
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask $strTaskName
   if($taskExists) {

    $taskExists.Description = "a daily  Report"

    $taskExists | set-scheduledtask -user $strUser -Password $strPassword
   }
```

The above piece of power shell code is to update existing schedule task. Could anyone please tell me how to update the **trigger** values?

Comment: and what does this to do with c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task returned from the `Get-ScheduledTask` cmdlet has a `Triggers` property where you can add / remove triggers.

Comment: $taskExists.Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $strTime.
I tried the above code but got exception Error: Exception setting "Trigger": "The property 'Trigger' cannot be found on this object.

Comment: `Triggers` not `Trigger`. Also you have to add a new trigger using the `Add` method, you can't just assign the property to the return value of above cmdlet. Note: You probably also want to remove the existing triggers....

Comment: I still get $false enabled triggers instead of $true enabled triggers, even when setting them on existing tasks. How do we fix that?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Unregister and set again clears the false trigger.        
unregister-scheduledtask -TaskName "*server_reboot*" -TaskPath '\' –confirm:$false –verbose –ea silentlycontinue;

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "reboot" -Xml (Get-Content "reboot.xml" | Out-String) -Force -User "domain\svcaccount" -Password "---"